# How drop columns by CLASSES

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
data_1 <- structure(list(Line = structure(1:4, .Label = c("K1", "K2", "K3", 
"K4"), class = "factor"), A = c(4L, 1L, -1L, 2L), B = c(3L, -2L, 
-1L, 4L), C = c(-1L, 1L, 2L, 5L), D = c(2L, -5L, 3L, -7L), E = c(4L, 
1L, 4L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I want drop `integer` columns. I try:

```
rapply(object = data_1, classes = 'integer', how = 'list', f = function(x) {
  x <- NULL
})
```

and

```
lapply(X = data_1, FUN = function(x) {
  Filter(f = is.integer, x = x) <- NULL
})
```

But doesn't work.

I also need to do this for a list:

```
list_1 <- list(data_1 = structure(list(Line = structure(1:4, .Label = c("K1", 
"K2", "K3", "K4"), class = "factor"), A = c(4L, 1L, -1L, 2L), 
B = c(3L, -2L, -1L, 4L), C = c(-1L, 1L, 2L, 5L), D = c(2L, 
-5L, 3L, -7L), E = c(4L, 1L, 4L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), data_2 = structure(list(Line = structure(1:4, .Label = c("K1", 
"K2", "K3", "K4"), class = "factor"), A = c(4L, 1L, -1L, 2L), 
B = c(3L, -2L, -1L, 4L), C = c(-1L, 1L, 2L, 5L), D = c(2L, 
-5L, 3L, -7L), E = c(4L, 1L, 4L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), data_3 = structure(list(Line = structure(1:4, .Label = c("K1", 
"K2", "K3", "K4"), class = "factor"), A = c(4L, 1L, -1L, 2L), 
B = c(3L, -2L, -1L, 4L), C = c(-1L, 1L, 2L, 5L), D = c(2L, 
-5L, 3L, -7L), E = c(4L, 1L, 4L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))
```

I try:

```
rapply(object = list_1, classes = 'integer', how = 'list', f = function(x) {
  rapply(x, rm(x))
})

lapply(X = list_1, FUN = function(x) {
  lapply(X = Filter(is.integer, x), rm(x))
})
```

But, also doesn't work.

Desire output:

```
  Line
1   K1
2   K2
3   K3
4   K4
```

I need a solution with `R base` only, not additional packages (with `dplyr` and your `_if` functions).

Comment: `data_1[, !sapply(data_1, is.integer), drop=FALSE]`

Comment: Try `data_1[!sapply(data_1, is.integer)]` or `lapply(list_1, function(i)i[!sapply(i, is.integer)])`

Answer (score 0):

here is a R base solution using `lapply`:

```
myfun <- function(df){
  idx <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(df)), function(x) class(df[,x])) != "integer"

  df[, idx]
}

lapply(list_1, myfun)
```